# Add tags to talk for many to many relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am creating an API endpoint that creates a new Talk with the tags that should be associated to the talk. I have a many to many relationship set up between tags and talks in my domain, see below for the relationship.

Tag.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Conferency.Domain
{
    public class Tag : IAuditable
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<TalkTag> TalkTags { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Talk.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Conferency.Domain
{
    public class Talk : IAuditable
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public List<TalkTag> TalkTags { get; set; }
        public DateTime Presented { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

TalkTag.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Conferency.Domain
{
    public class TalkTag
    {
        public int TalkId { get; set; }
        public Talk Talk { get; set; }
        public int TagId { get; set; }
        public Tag Tag { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ConferencyContext.cs (Deleted irrelevant code)

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;
using System;
using Conferency.Domain;

namespace Conferency.Data
{
    public class ConferencyContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Talk> Talks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TalkTag> TagTalks { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<TalkTag>()
                .HasKey(s => new { s.TalkId, s.TagId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<TalkTag>()
                .HasOne(pt => pt.Talk)
                .WithMany(p => p.TalkTags)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TalkId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<TalkTag>()
                .HasOne(pt => pt.Tag)
                .WithMany(t => t.TalkTags)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TagId);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

TalkViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Conferency.Application.Models
{
    public class TalkViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public List<String> Tags { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to create a talk and its tags (attach if they exists, create if they don't). I am not sure in what order to accomplish this. Do I have to query each tag to check if they exist or is there a findOrCreate method I could use? How do I create a TalkTag record if the Talk isn't created yet? Is there an elegant way to accomplish this that I am not understanding?

TalkRepository.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Conferency.Domain;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Conferency.Data
{
    public class TalkRepository : ITalkRepository
    {
        private ConferencyContext _context;

        public TalkRepository(ConferencyContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void Add(Talk entity)
        {
            _context.Add(entity);
        }

        public void AddWithTags(Talk entity, List<String> tags)
        {
            // Create Talk
            // Query for each tag
            // Create if they don't exist
            // Attach to talk
            // ??
        }

        public IEnumerable<Talk> GetAllTalks()
        {
            return _context.Talks
                .Include(c => c.TalkTags)
                .OrderBy(c => c.Presented)
                .ToList();
        }

        public Talk GetTalk(int id)
        {
            return _context.Talks
                .Include(c => c.TalkTags)
                .Where(c => c.Id == id)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public async Task<bool> SaveAllAsync()
        {
            return (await _context.SaveChangesAsync()) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to c# and I'm trying to learn best practices and familiarizing myself with EF and ASP.NET Core so hopefully somebody can help guide me in the right path. The full solution is here if you want to take a look https://github.com/bliitzkrieg/Conferency

I tried solving it myself but Im getting a NullPointerException, here is my attempt at a solution:

TalksController.cs

```
  [HttpPost()]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]TalkViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Creating a new Talk");

                List<Tag> tags = _tagRepo.FindOrCreateTags(model.Tags);

                Talk talk = new Talk { Name = model.Name, Url = model.Url };

                List<TalkTag> talkTags = new List<TalkTag>();
                tags.ForEach(tag =>
                {
                    var talkTag = new TalkTag { TagId = tag.Id, Talk = talk };
                    talkTags.Add(talkTag);
                });

                talk.TalkTags.AddRange(talkTags); // Exception being thrown here
                _repo.Add(talk);

                if (await _repo.SaveAllAsync())
                {
                    string newUri = Url.Link("TalkGet", new { id = talk.Id });
                    return Created(newUri, talk);
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("Could not save Talk");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Threw exception while saving Talk: {ex}");
            }

            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

TagRepository.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Conferency.Domain;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;

namespace Conferency.Data
{
    public class TagRepository: ITagRepository
    {
        private ConferencyContext _context;

        public TagRepository(ConferencyContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void Add(Tag entity)
        {
            _context.Add(entity);
        }

        public List<Tag> FindOrCreateTags(List<string> tags)
        {
            List<Tag> _tags = new List<Tag>();
            tags.ForEach(t =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var tag = _context.Tags
                       .Where(c => c.Name == t)
                       .FirstOrDefault();

                    if (tag != null)
                    {
                        _tags.Add(tag);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Tag created = new Tag { Name = t };
                        this.Add(created);
                        _tags.Add(created);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }

            });

            return _tags;
        }

        public async Task<bool> SaveAllAsync()
        {
            return (await _context.SaveChangesAsync()) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since none of the properties of your entities are `virtual`, it appears you don't have the navigation properties set up correctly.

Comment: I don't know much about virtual entities but I followed the many to many guide on the EF core documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships).

Comment: You should provide your TalkViewModel code as well. From what I can see of your code, I'd guess you need a List<TagViewModel> property on your TalkViewModel that has the Tag Id, Tag Text, and a bool "Selected" property. Then when you pass the TalkViewModel to your repo, filter out the selected TagViewModels and for each one, add a TalkTag with the proper TagId to you TalkTags property on your Talk. EF should take care of adding the proper TalkId upon SaveChanges().

Comment: If your users can dynamically add Tags on your Talk form, give them an Id of 0, then filter those TagViewModels and add them as a new Tag to the Tag property on your TalkTag. Let me know if this works, I'll provide a formal answer.

Comment: I added the TalkViewModel. I'll attempt your solution this evening and give you an update

Comment: @Luca I was a little wordy yesterday. The crux is, if the Tag exists (which, you have to query for tags to populate user form), create a TalkTag with that TagId and the new Talk as its properties. If the tag doesn't exist, create a TalkTag with a new Tag and the new Talk as its properties, then add it to your _context. EF should take care of the rest.

Comment: @MichaelTranchida That worked!! I have a small bug where in my talk fetch its not pulling the Tag name but I'll figure that one out this week. Thank you so much! I really appreciate all the help. If you submit it as an answer I will mark it as the answer.

If its not too much to ask and you have a moment, could you checkout the controller method and give me some feedback on my implementation and general code style. 

Here's the [controller](https://github.com/bliitzkrieg/Conferency/blob/96e55543dfc6ea89407ec580e4a7bc4ed6d99d9c/Conferency.Application/Controllers/TalksController.cs#L66)

Comment: @Luca If you're using EF Core, you should add that as a tag. I'll go ahead and provide comments as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `TalkViewModel` add a `List<TagViewModel>` property with the following properties:

```
public int TagId { get; set; }
public string TagName { get; set; }
public bool Selected { get; set; }
```

When you pass the TalkViewModel to your repo, filter out the selected `TagViewModel`s and for each one, add a `TalkTag` with the proper `TagId` to your `TalkTags` property on your `Talk`. EF should take care of adding the proper `TalkId` upon `_context.SaveChanges()`.

If the `Tag` doesn't exist, create a `TalkTag` with a new `Tag` and the new `Talk` as its properties, then add it to your `_context`. EF should take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized your TalkTags collection which causes the nullpointer. Try this when initializing the Talk object:

```
Talk talk = new Talk { Name = model.Name, Url = model.Url, TalkTags = new List<TalkTag>() };
```

Do you need more properties on a TalkTag object? Otherwise you could just have `List<Talk>` in the Tag class and `List<Tag>` in the Talk class and the mapping will be done by EF (a TalkTag table will be created in the DB).

Michael Tranchida already described the approach for adding the objects to the context.